# How could I avoid credential popup powershell window in sql server agent?

Tags: .net, powershell, sharepoint, powershell-3.0, sharepoint-online

I've been struggling to make my powershell script work for pulling data from a Sharepoint list to sql server via SQL Agent. And to do so, I'm using `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` module and added the following code to take credentials automatically.

```bsh
$filePath="https://AnyCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/AnySite"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $filePath -UseWebLogin
```

But when I put this in sql agent it doesn't work as it does in powershell or even in task scheduler.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ5K2.png)
By the error message, I found that the problem is with this credential pop up window. So how could I avoid this? How could I get the connection to sharepoint site without putting this line of code.

The picture belows shows my settings and the last line of code is causing the error.
[My current job settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwZb0.png)

Sincerely, I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Luis Antonio Espinoza,

If you do not want the cmdlet `Connect-PnPOnline` popup the login window, why not hard code your credential in the script:

```
$Username='abc@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
$Password = '*****'

#region Credentials
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

#connect to site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $filePath -Credentials $PSCredentials
```